# distinct count in SSAS

Tags: ssas, cube, olap-cube

I have 4 columns in a fact order table `OrderDescriptionID`,  `OrderID`,  `CustomerID`, and  `DateKey`. The data in the rows is such that `orderID` defines 1 order by a customer. If the customer has placed one order with multiple items then the `orderDescriptionID` defines the different objects in the order.

See the example below:

[image]

What I want my cube to do is represent the personID once and, show the distinct orders and a total of how many items they ordered (this is not necessary but person and distinct orders is). As an example see the image below

[image]

> Note: If OrderItemsCount is a lot of work I can pass on it, I am more
>   interested in distinct orders made by the customer.

Answer (score 0):

after some hard work on internet and not being able to find the answer, I went back to the SSAS book and got the answer.

Right-Click on the fact table and select New Measure, in the Usage drop down select Distinct Count, select the table and the column on which you want your distinct count to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct count will work, but be careful of the performance. SSAS will create a separate measure group to help, but worth having a read about them.